# C++. Даны два массива: А [M] и B[N] (M и N вводятся с клавиатуры)

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, указатели, динамические-массивы

Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать общие элементы двух массивов.

```
    int sizeA, sizeB;
    cout << "Введите размер первого массива: ";
    cin >> sizeA;
    cout << "Введите размер второго массива: ";
    cin >> sizeB;
    int *arrA = new int[sizeA];
    int *arrB = new int[sizeB];
    cout << "\n\nПервый массив: ";
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
    {
        arrA[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
        cout << arrA[x] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n\nВторой массив: ";
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
    {
        arrB[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
        cout << arrB[x] << " ";
    }

    int tmp = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeB; y++)
        {
            if (arrA[x] == arrB[y])
            {
                tmp++;
            }
        }
    }

    int sizeC = tmp;
    int *arrtmp = new int[sizeC];
    tmp = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < sizeB; y++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < sizeA; z++)
        {
            if (arrB[y] == arrA[z])
            {
                arrtmp[tmp] = arrB[y];
                tmp++;
            }
        }
    }

    int *arrC = new int[sizeC];
    cout << "\n\nТретий массив: ";
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeC; x++)
    {
        arrC[x] = arrtmp[x];
        cout << arrC[x] << " ";
    }

    delete arrA;
    delete arrB;
    delete arrC;
    delete arrtmp;
```

Это мой код. Все вроде бы правильно работает, но если в первом или во втором массиве несколько одинаковых чисел аналогов которому только одно число в другом массиве, лишние числа тоже считается в tmp. tmp -> минимальное количество чисел для третьего массива.
Если в arrA = {1, 2, 3, 3} а в arrB = {2, 5, 3, 6, 7} то вывод будет arrC = {2, 3, 3, 3, 3}. Как сделать чтобы было {2, 3} ?

---

@Harry, @LLENN, @AnT попробовал отсортировать вот таким образом, так мне ближе просто:

```
void sort(int *arrN, int sizeN)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeN; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeN; j++)
        {
            if (arrN[j + 1] > arrN[j])
            {
                tmp = arrN[j + 1];
                arrN[j + 1] = arrN[j];
                arrN[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В итоге получился такой код:

```
{
        int sizeA, sizeB;
        cout << "Введите размер первого массива: ";
        cin >> sizeA;
        cout << "Введите размер второго массива: ";
        cin >> sizeB;
        int *arrA = new int[sizeA];
        int *arrB = new int[sizeB];
        cout << "\n\nПервый массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            arrA[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nВторой массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
        {
            arrB[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << arrB[x] << " ";
        }

        sort(arrA, sizeA);
        sort(arrB, sizeB);

        int *arrC = new int[sizeA < sizeB ? sizeA : sizeB];
        int sizeC = 0;

        for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < sizeA && y < sizeB; )
        {
            if (arrA[x] < arrB[y]) ++x;
            else if (arrA[x] > arrB[y]) ++y;
            else
            {
                arrC[sizeC++] = arrA[x];
                x++; y++;
            }
        }

        cout << "\n\nПервый массив (Отсортированный): ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nВторой массив (Отсортированный): ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
        {
            cout << arrB[x] << " ";
        }

        cout << "\n\nТретий массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeC; x++)
        {
            cout << arrC[x] << " ";
        }

        delete arrA;
        delete arrB;
        delete arrC;
}
```

Вот то, что вывелось:

Введите размер первого массива: 5
Введите размер второго массива: 7

Первый массив: 1 4 5 2 4
Второй массив: 3 2 2 7 3 3 1

Первый массив (Отсортированный): 5 4 4 2 1
Второй массив (Отсортированный): 7 3 3 3 2 2 1

Третий массив:

---

Должно было быть:

Третий массив: 2, 1

---

Не знаю что упустил или неправильно понял, ответьте пожалуйста.

---

Нашел свою ошибку. Она заключалась в сортировке. Вот исправленный код пузырьковой сортировки:

```
void sort(int *arrN, int sizeN)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeN; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sizeN; ++j)
        {
            if (arrN[j] < arrN[i])
            {
                tmp = arrN[j];
                arrN[j] = arrN[i];
                arrN[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы отсортировал оба массива, а потом шел от меньших к большим и сравнивал - ну, думаю, идея понятна даже при таком кратком намеке? :) Кстати, массивы - это сверхусловие, или хотя бы `vector` можно? (О `set` не спрашиваю :)) Кстати, из условия непонятно - например, при {2,3,3,4,5} и {2,6,3,3,7,8} что должно быть - {2,3} или {2,3,3}?

Comment: Ну вектор я еще не изучал да и по заданию он не требуется. И вообще я думал, что вектор это одномерный массив :)

Comment: Должно быть {2, 3, 3}

Comment: Потому, что в первом массиве две тройки как и во втором. Если была бы одна в первом и две во втором то вывод - одна. Второй тройке не чего было бы сопоставить.

Comment: @Hiko Moff: Что значит тогда требование "минимально возможного размера"? Размер результата в вашей задаче определен *однозначно*. Никакого выбора тут нет. Откуда тогда взялось требование "минимально возможного размера" и к чему оно тут? Если бы требовалось получить `{ 2, 3 }`, тогда еще можно было бы понять, о какой "минимальности" идет речь. Но если правильный ответ `{ 2, 3, 3 }`, то при чем здесь вообще "минимальность"?

Comment: @Hiko Moff Правильно ли я понял, что если первый массив - это { 2, 2 } и второй массив точно такой же, то есть равен { 2, 2 }, то общим массивом будет также { 2, 2 }?

Comment: Ну если размер первого массива arrA[4] а второго массива arrB[3] и они состоят из {0,1,2,3} и {1, 2, 3} соответственно то на выводе должно быть в массиве arrC -> {1, 2, 3} и соответственно размер arrC[3] @AnT. Да Влад, вы правильно поняли

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow

Comment: @Hiko Moff Уточните, что вы мне ответили?:)

Comment: @Hiko Moff: Размер этого результирующего массива *однозначно определен* входными данными и равен именно 3. С таким же успехом можно сказать ,что нужно найти массива "**максимально** возможного размера". Все равно размер будет равен именно 3. Поэтому требование "минимальности" - бессмысленно и здесь совершенно ни к чему.

Comment: Да Влад, вы правильно поняли @Vlad from Moscow на сообщение 
 - Правильно ли я понял, что если первый массив - это { 2, 2 } и второй массив точно такой же, то есть равен { 2, 2 }, то общим массивом будет также { 2, 2 }?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если исходные массивы не должны изменяться, то есть если вы не должны менять исходные массивы с помощью их сортировки, то соответствующий код с использованием циклов может выглядеть следующим образом, как показано в демонстрационной программе ниже:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    const int MIN_VALUE = 1;
    const int MAX_VALUE = 8;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of the firts array: ";
    size_t n1;
    std::cin >> n1;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of the second array: ";
    size_t n2;
    std::cin >> n2;

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    int *a1 = new int[n1];

    std::cout << "\nFirst  array: ";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++ )
    {
        a1[i] = std::rand() % ( MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE ) + MIN_VALUE;
        std::cout << a1[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    int *a2 = new int[n2];

    std::cout << "Second array: ";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n2; i++ )
    {
        a2[i] = std::rand() % ( MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE ) + MIN_VALUE;
        std::cout << a2[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    size_t n3 = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++ )
    {
        size_t count = 1;

        for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        {
            if ( a1[j] == a1[i] ) ++count;
        }

        for ( size_t j = 0; count != 0 && j < n2; j++ )
        {
            if ( a2[j] == a1[i] ) --count;
        }

        if ( count == 0 ) ++n3;
    }

    int *a3 = new int[n3];

    size_t m = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++ )
    {
        size_t count = 1;

        for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        {
            if ( a1[j] == a1[i] ) ++count;
        }

        for ( size_t j = 0; count != 0 && j < n2; j++ )
        {
            if ( a2[j] == a1[i] ) --count;
        }

        if ( count == 0 ) a3[m++] = a1[i];
    }

    std::cout << "The common elements: ";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n3; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << a3[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete [] a3;
    delete [] a2;
    delete [] a1;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль, к примеру, может выглядеть следующим образом

```
Enter the size of the firts array: 7
Enter the size of the second array: 10

First  array: 2 6 4 1 2 3 3 
Second array: 4 6 6 7 2 5 1 7 4 5 
The common elements: 2 6 4 1
```

То же самое может быть реализовано с использованием стандартных алгоритмов и стандартного контейнера `std::vector<int>`, который берет на себя ответственность по выделению динамически массива.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
    const int MIN_VALUE = 1;
    const int MAX_VALUE = 8;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of the firts array: ";
    size_t n1;
    std::cin >> n1;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of the second array: ";
    size_t n2;
    std::cin >> n2;

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    std::vector<int> v1;
    v1.reserve( n1 );

    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v1 ), n1, 
                     [=]
                     {
                        return std::rand() % ( MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE ) + MIN_VALUE;
                     } );

    std::cout << "\nFirst  array: ";
    for ( const int &item : v1 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::vector<int> v2;
    v1.reserve( n2 );

    std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( v2 ), n2, 
                     [=]
                     {
                        return std::rand() % ( MAX_VALUE - MIN_VALUE ) + MIN_VALUE;
                     } );

    std::cout << "Second  array: ";
    for ( const int &item : v2 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    size_t n3 = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++ )
    {
        size_t count = std::count( std::begin( v1 ), std::next( std::begin( v1 ), i ), v1[i] ) + 1;
        std::find_if( std::begin( v2 ), std::end( v2 ), 
                      [&]( const int &x )
                      {
                        return ( count -= x == v1[i] ) == 0;
                      } );

        if ( count == 0 ) ++n3;
    }

    std::vector<int> v3;
    v3.reserve( n3 );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++ )
    {
        size_t count = std::count( std::begin( v1 ), std::next( std::begin( v1 ), i ), v1[i] ) + 1;
        std::find_if( std::begin( v2 ), std::end( v2 ), 
                      [&]( const int &x )
                      {
                        return ( count -= x == v1[i] ) == 0;
                      } );

        if ( count == 0 ) v3.push_back( v1[i] );
    }

    std::cout << "The common elements: ";

    for ( const int &item : v3 )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль, к примеру, может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Enter the size of the firts array: 7
Enter the size of the second array: 10

First  array: 2 7 2 6 5 3 6 
Second  array: 5 5 3 7 5 7 2 4 2 6 
The common elements: 2 7 2 6 5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

А, держите. Ваша главная ерунда - вы пытаетесь сравнивать все элементы одного массива со всеми элементами второго... А это чушь.

Вот реализация моей идеи - сортировка и простое линейное сравнение. Как я понимаю, сортировка тоже за пределами разрешенного? Потому набросал простой пузырек...

По сути - основное вот:

```
sort(arrA, sizeA);
sort(arrB, sizeB);

int *arrC = new int[sizeA < sizeB ? sizeA : sizeB];
size_t sizeC = 0;

for(size_t a = 0, b = 0; a < sizeA && b < sizeB; )
{
    if (arrA[a] < arrB[b]) ++a;
    else if (arrA[a] > arrB[b]) ++b;
    else
    {
        arrC[sizeC++] = arrA[a];
        a++; b++;
    }
}

cout << "\n\nResult array: ";
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeC; i++)
{
    cout << arrC[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Ну, а полностью - [тут](https://ideone.com/hCjVN3).

Comment: а что означает [sizeA < sizeB ? sizeA : sizeB] ?? Просто впервые вижу такое

Comment: @HikoMoff: тернарный оператор, если `sizeA < sizeB` Будет использован `sizeA` в противном случае `sizeB`.

Answer (score 1):

типичный линейный алгоритм пересечения двух множеств, работает в отсортированных множествах

```
int* task(int *a, int *b, int m, int n, int &k)
{
    int i(0); // индекс для а
    int j(0); // индекс для b

    int *c = new int[m];

    while (i < m && j <n)
    {
        if (a[i] == b[j])
        {
            c[k] = a[i];
            ++i;
            ++j;
            ++k;
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[j])
        {
            ++i;
        }
        else if (a[i] > b[j])
        {
            ++j;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

void read(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < n;++i)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

void write(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < n;++i)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    cin >> m >> n;

    int *a = new int[m];
    int *b = new int[n];

    read(a, m);
    read(b, n);

    int k = 0;
    int *c = task(a, b, m, n, k);

    write(c, k);

    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;

    return 0;
}
```