# C++ Третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массива A, которые не включаются в массив B

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массива A, которые не включаются в массив B.

```
void sort(int *arrN, int sizeN)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeN; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < sizeN; ++j)
        {
            if (arrN[j] < arrN[i])
            {
                tmp = arrN[j];
                arrN[j] = arrN[i];
                arrN[i] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
int sizeA, sizeB;
        cout << "Введите размер первого массива: ";
        cin >> sizeA;
        cout << "Введите размер второго массива: ";
        cin >> sizeB;
        int *arrA = new int[sizeA];
        int *arrB = new int[sizeB];
        cout << "\n\nПервый массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            arrA[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nВторой массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
        {
            arrB[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << arrB[x] << " ";
        }

        sort(arrA, sizeA);
        sort(arrB, sizeB);

        cout << "\n\nПервый массив (Отсортированный): ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nВторой массив (Отсортированный): ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
        {
            cout << arrB[x] << " ";
        }

        int *arrC = new int[sizeA < sizeB ? sizeA : sizeB];

        int sizeC = 0;

        for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < sizeA && y < sizeB; )
        {
            if (arrA[x] == arrB[y])
            {
                ++x;
            }
            else if (arrA[x] == arrB[y])
            {
                ++y;
            }
            else
            {
                arrC[sizeC] = arrA[x];
                sizeC++;
                x++; y++;
            }
        }

        cout << "\n\nТретий массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeC; x++)
        {
            cout << arrC[x] << " ";
        }

        delete[] arrA;
        delete[] arrB;
        delete[] arrC;
}
```

### Выводит как пример (при arrA[5], arrB[7]):

Первый массив: 3 1 6 1 5

Второй массив: 3 4 6 1 6 4 4

Первый массив (Отсортированный): 1 1 3 5 6

Второй массив (Отсортированный): 1 3 4 4 4 6 6

Третий массив: 3 5 6

---

Не могу определить ошибку.

---

Попробовал проверять элементы двумя циклами:

```
for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < sizeA && y < sizeB; )
        {
            for (int z = 0, n = 0; z < sizeA && n < sizeB; )
            {
                if (arrA[z] == arrB[n])
                {
                    ++z;
                }
                else if (arrA[z] == arrB[n])
                {
                    ++n;
                }
                else
                {
                    arrC[sizeC] = arrA[z];
                    sizeC++;
                    z++; n++;
                }
            }
            x++, y++;
        }
```

Но программа багается и неприличные звуки виндовса.

---

@Ibragim Magomedov

```
cout << "Даны два массива: А[M] и B[N] (M и  N вводятся с клавиатуры). Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массива A, которые не включаются в массив B\n\n";
        int sizeA, sizeB;
        cout << "Введите размер первого массива: ";
        cin >> sizeA;
        cout << "Введите размер второго массива: ";
        cin >> sizeB;
        int *arrA = new int[sizeA];
        int *arrB = new int[sizeB];
        cout << "\n\nПервый массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            arrA[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nВторой массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
        {
            arrB[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << arrB[x] << " ";
        }

        sort(arrA, sizeA);
        sort(arrB, sizeB);

        cout << "\n\nПервый массив (Отсортированный): ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nВторой массив (Отсортированный): ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
        {
            cout << arrB[x] << " ";
        }

        int *arrC = new int[sizeA < sizeB ? sizeA : sizeB];

        int sizeC = 0;

        bool no_write = false;
        for (int a = 0, c = 0; a < sizeA; a++)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < sizeB; b++)
                if (arrA[a] == arrB[b])
                {
                    no_write = true;
                    break;
                }
            if (no_write = false)
                if (arrC[c] != arrA[a])
                {
                    arrC[c] = arrA[a];
                    c++;
                }
                else no_write = true;
        }

        cout << "\n\nТретий массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeC; x++)
        {
            cout << arrC[x] << " ";
        }

        delete[] arrA;
        delete[] arrB;
        delete[] arrC;
```

---

Исправил свой код и вот готовый рабочий вариант.

```
{
        cout << "Даны два массива: А[M] и B[N] (M и  N вводятся с клавиатуры). Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массива A, которые не включаются в массив B\n\n";
        int sizeA, sizeB;
        cout << "Введите размер первого массива: ";
        cin >> sizeA;
        cout << "Введите размер второго массива: ";
        cin >> sizeB;
        int *arrA = new int[sizeA];
        int *arrB = new int[sizeB];
        cout << "\n\nПервый массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            arrA[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nВторой массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
        {
            arrB[x] = rand() % 9 + 1;
            cout << arrB[x] << " ";
        }

        sort(arrA, sizeA);
        sort(arrB, sizeB);

        cout << "\n\nПервый массив (Отсортированный): ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            cout << arrA[x] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n\nВторой массив (Отсортированный): ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
        {
            cout << arrB[x] << " ";
        }

        int *arrC = new int[sizeA < sizeB ? sizeA : sizeB];
        int sizeC = 0;

        cout << endl << endl << endl;

        bool flag;
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeA; x++)
        {
            flag = false;
            for (int y = 0; y < sizeB; y++)
            {
                if (arrA[x] == arrB[y])
                {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag == false)
            {
                arrC[sizeC] = arrA[x];
                sizeC++;
            }
        }

        cout << "\n\nТретий массив: ";
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeC; x++)
        {
            cout << arrC[x] << " ";
        }

        delete[] arrA;
        delete[] arrB;
        delete[] arrC;
    }
```

Comment: Ошибка в алгоритме сравнения элементов массивов

Comment: А каким образом это исправить? Что упустил или где не туда завернул?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [C++. Даны два массива: А \[M\] и B\[N\] (M и N вводятся с клавиатуры)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968499/c-%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%90-m-%d0%b8-bn-m-%d0%b8-n-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b)

Comment: Не дубликат, разные требования. @MBo

Comment: Процедура слияния решает обе проблемы - создаёт множество пересечения и два множества разностей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так понимаю вы имели ввиду разность множеств, код ниже можете попробовать
(работает в отсортированных множествах)

```
int* subtract(int *a, int *b, int m, int n, int &k)
{
    int i(0); // индекс для а
    int j(0); // индекс для b

    int *buf = new int[m];

    while (i < m)
    {
        if (j == n)
        {
            buf[k] = a[i];
            ++i;
            ++k;
        }
        else if (a[i] == b[j])
        {
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }
        else if (a[i] < b[j])
        {
            buf[k] = a[i];
            ++i;
            ++k;
        }
        else if (a[i] > b[j])
        {
            buf[k] = a[i];
            ++j;
            ++k;
        }
    }
    return buf;
}

void read(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < n;++i)
    {
    cin >> a[i];
    }
}

void write(int *a, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < n;++i)
    {
    cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    cin >> m >> n;

    int *a = new int[m];
    int *b = new int[n];

    read(a, m);
    read(b, n);

    int k = 0;
    int *c = subtract(a, b, m, n, k);

    write(c, k);

    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;
    delete[] c;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем варианте кода есть некоторые непонятки, например два одинаковых условия, где второе никогда не выполнится и т.д.

В результате, итоговый массив заполнялся всякими разными рандомными элементами.

Если не  особо понимаете в чем ошибка, и у вас выходит что-то не так, можете попробовать пройтись по коду , как это делает машина. Каждую итерацию, каждое действие, отчасти это может вам помочь в понимании не только того, как работает машина, но и каким образом работает тот или иной алгоритм, и возможно понять, как можно его улучшить, изменить и тд.

Вот рабочий алгоритм, который ближе к вашему коду:

```js
 for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < sizeA && y < sizeB; )
{
 if (arrA[x] > arrB[y]) y++; else if (arrA[x] == arrB[y]) { x++; y++; }
 else
 {
  arrC[sizeC] = arrA[x];
  sizeC++;
  x++;
 }
 
}
```

Comment: Первый массив: 7 6 8 9 8

Второй массив: 3 3 5 8 5 2

Первый массив (Отсортированный): 6 7 8 8 9

Второй массив (Отсортированный): 2 3 3 5 5 8

Третий массив: 8  // Выводит такой ответ @Gin Tasan

Comment: @HikoMoff общий элемент первого и второго - 8 или я не понял вопроса и надо , что бы выводило 8 8 8 ?

Comment: Боже, глубоко извиняюсь, неправильно написал задание в заголовке. Требовалось - > "Даны два массива: А[M] и B[N] (M и  N вводятся с клавиатуры). Необходимо создать третий массив минимально возможного размера, в котором нужно собрать элементы массива A, которые не включаются в массив B"

Comment: @HikoMoff , ну вы даете ) Исправьте ТЗ вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Простым поэлементным сравнением не пробовали? Должно по идеи помочь.

```
bool no_write = false;
for (int a = 0, int c = 0; a < size(arrayA); a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < size(arrayb); b++)
        if(arrayA[a] == arrayB[b])
        {
           no_write = true
           break;
        }
    if(no_write = false)
        if(arrayC[c] != arrayA[a])
        {
            arrayC[c] = arrayA[a];
            c++;
        }
    else no_write = true;
}
```

Comment: Не заработало должным образом :( В вопросе скинул весь код и + то что вы написали. Возможно сам неправильно отредактировал и так далее. @Ibragim Magomedov

Comment: Ещё нужна помощь?